# What did Captain Cold initially request from Barry in The Flash S01E22?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, the-flash

Spoiler alert :

> To transfer the five metahumans to Lian Yu, Barry needs Snart's help for backup. However, Snart asked for something that Barry immediately said it's impossible to get or to give to Snart.

What did Snart ask of Barry?

[image]

Comment: given what Barry *actually* did for him, it's hard to imagine what he could have asked for that was worse, unless it was just a ridiculous sum of money...

Comment: A *blanket?!?!?!??!*

Answer (score 6):

Leonard probably asked for powers (like meta humans). In the new 52 comics The Rogues placed their themed weapons into [Elias'](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Darwin_Elias_(Prime_Earth)) genome recoding device, and fused their DNA with the weapons. Captain cold then gets the power of Cryokinesis. Leonard probably wanted Barry to make him into a meta-human, so he could be more powerful.

Sorry, im not 100% sure.

Comment: Given the nature of the series and its numerous easter eggs to the New 52, it's a very reasonable possibility.